# compiling xkbcomp (Xorg App)

Tags: c, x11, cross-compiling, autotools, xorg

I'm trying to compile xkbcomp (from xorg App) but I got the following errors :

```
warning: libxcb.so.1, needed by /lib/libX11.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
/lib/libX11.so: undefined reference to `xcb_connection_has_error'
/lib/libX11.so: undefined reference to `xcb_poll_for_reply'
/lib/libX11.so: undefined reference to `xcb_get_maximum_request_length'
/lib/libX11.so: undefined reference to `xcb_get_file_descriptor'
/lib/libX11.so: undefined reference to `xcb_connect'
/lib/libX11.so: undefined reference to `xcb_wait_for_reply'
/lib/libX11.so: undefined reference to `xcb_get_setup'
/lib/libX11.so: undefined reference to `xcb_wait_for_event'
/lib/libX11.so: undefined reference to `xcb_poll_for_event'
/lib/libX11.so: undefined reference to `xcb_parse_display'
/lib/libX11.so: undefined reference to `xcb_generate_id'
/lib/libX11.so: undefined reference to `xcb_disconnect'
/lib/libX11.so: undefined reference to `xcb_take_socket'
/lib/libX11.so: undefined reference to `xcb_writev'
/lib/libX11.so: undefined reference to `xcb_connect_to_display_with_auth_info'
```

Note: libX11 and libxcb are successfully been compiled (using autotools) and I got all my ".so" shared libraries and header files. But the problem still existing.

How can I solve that??

Comment: where have your compiled libX11 and libxcd ? Did you installed them ? It seems xkbcomp used default libraries, not yours... missing some parameters to indicate where to search for libraries...

Comment: It's not about where to search, my compiler already now that. It needs only to link with the needed lib.

Answer (score 9):

I had solve the problem, I needed just to add "-lxcb" to my LDFLAGS. Now, it works fine. Thanks –

Comment: You can accept your own answer, you even get a special badge for it!

Comment: @JackKelly really? Is there a badge for that?

Answer (score 0):

In Linux, using GCC you can use the flags

```
gcc input.c -o output -I/usr/lib/X11R6 -lX11
```

Comment: I had solve the problem, I needed just to add  "-lxcb" to my LDFLAGS. Now, it works fine. Thanks